# The case of the sneaky backslash - Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm missing something very obvious here, but I just cant see it.

I've got:

```
string input = @"999\abc.txt";
string pattern = @"\\(.*)";
string output = Regex.Match(input,pattern).ToString();
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

My result is:

```
\abc.txt
```

**I don't want the slash** and cant figure out why it's sneaking into the output. I tried flipping the pattern, and the slash winds up in the output again:

```
string pattern = @"^(.*)\\";
```

and get:

```
999\
```

Strange. The result is fine in Osherove's Regulator. Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Match` is the *entire* match; you want the first group;

```
string output = Regex.Match(input,pattern).Groups[1].Value;
```

(from memory; may vary slightly)

Comment: Just to clarify for anyone wondering why it's index of 1 instead of index of 0 into groups, it's because index of 0 gives back a group which represents the entire match.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups.aspx) to get only the group, not the entire match:

```
string output = Regex.Match(input, pattern).Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the results in `Groups`, not the entire matched text.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups(v=VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Marc's answer, you can use a [zero-width positive lookbehind assertion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#zerowidth_positive_lookbehind_assertion) in your pattern :

```
string pattern = @"(?<=\\)(.*)";
```

This will match "\" but exclude it from the capture

Answer (score 0):

You could try the match prefix/postfix but exclude options.

**Match everything after the first slash /**

```
(?<=\\)(.*)$
```

**Match everything after the last slash /**

```
(?<=\\)([^\\]*)$
```

**Match everything before the last slash /**

```
^(.*)(?=\\)
```

BTW, download [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) for testing regular expressions, total life-saver.